# TailwindCSS is not getting applied in my project

Tags: react-native, tailwind-css

I am trying this but it's not working, none of the attributes in the 'className' are working, what am I doing wrong? the app loads but the changes dont apply

```js
import { Text, View } from 'react-native';

export default function App() {
  return (

    <View>
      <Text className="flex-1 items-center text-red-500">hello</Text>
      <StatusBar style="auto" />
    </View>
  );
}
```

I have installed and checked all the dependencies at this point but it's not applying

Comment: It works, I was not handling the syntax properly